# The best way to show one-time action on a modal?

Tags: design-patterns, modal-windows

I'm working on a feature where the user is going to attach warehouses to their company branches. The process has two steps (input general information and define the coverage area of said warehouse). Currently, the user clicks on a button that opens a modal where they fill in these two steps.

Now, I need them to select one of two types of coverage areas first. This selection will only happen once (when they add a warehouse for the first time) and will apply to all the warehouses attached later.

I don't want to add modal on top of modal, and I don't think a one-time action justifies turning it into a page. Showing the selection on the modal we have today might give the user the wrong impression that they can choose a coverage area type for each warehouse they add, or get them confused when they don't find the selection on the second time.

Is there a pattern to show one-time inputs like this?

Comment: Is there a reason the "coverage area type" is not chosen at account creation? Since it seems to be attached to the user, rather than the warehouse, it seems like that would be the best time to select it.

If it must be selected in the modal, the clearest option may be to just craft some language like "you have not chosen a coverage type. This will be applied to all warehouses in your account" etc.